# Error with simplejson dependency when installing Eve

Tags: python, python-3.x, eve, simplejson, pipenv

I am new to Python and am trying to install Eve. I have Python 3.6.3 installed and am using pipenv. When I run `pipenv install eve` it fails with the error (here's an excerpt):

```
    running build_ext
    building 'simplejson._speedups' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'
    _______________________________________

Error: An error occurred while installing eve!
  Failed building wheel for simplejson
```

From what I can tell, this path is for the Windows 8.1 SDK.

What can I do to fix this? Do I need to install this SDK in order for simplejson to work? I don't really want to install this SDK, so why does simplejson need this?

I suspect that I don't actually need this SDK as I assume all of this can normally be executed in a Linux environment. Why would this dependency exist when executing on a Windows 7 machine as I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Yes, I do need the SDK. Windows compilers are required to "Install a non-pure Python package from sources with Pip" on Windows machines and are included in Microsoft Build Tools. More information can be found here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers