# unable to install django-rest-swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am trying to install **django-rest-swagger** into a virtual machine but it is giving error **Failed Building wheel for simplejson**
i tried searching for some solution but as far as i was able to understand is that there is some dependency on visual studio... i have microsoft visual studio 2015 installed on my system
I am attaching the installation report and see just before the error its written unable to find specified path and there is a path for library of visual studio

[image: first it shows that the specified directory wasn't found]

[image: Error that came up while installing the package in continuation of the first image]

Comment: No clear question

Comment: Please see the images attached along with the question

Comment: i have attached the images of the error i came through. Please see it ones

Comment: Do you face the same error while doing `pip install simplejson`? Can you try that and edit your question with any new problem that shows up. Also please don't post screenshots, copy paste the text in the error message and format it using `Ctrl+K`

Comment: Yes i tried that and still getting the same error.. and i will take care of your suggestion regarding way of posting the question...thank you

Comment: Can you try installing `simplejson` without `wheel`: `pip install --no-use-wheel simplejson`? Can you also try updating `pip`?

Comment: it says there is no such option as **--no-use-wheel**

Comment: I have a feeling that this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47552771/7255359 Windows compilers require you to install with Microsoft Build Tools.